# import Bulk data xlsx to mysql ? couldn't convert xls

Tags: mysql, sqlite, xls, xlsx

I need to import more than 280 000 records to mysql (sqlite also fine). I have the xlsx format only. I couldn't convert this to xls file. Is there way or import option in latest version or any better tool available. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Data Import](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/data-export-import.html) tool in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/).

Open Data Import wizard, select 'MS Excel 2007' format, specify other options and press Import.

Answer (score 3):

See if you can convert the xslx file to csv format then follow this post: [Import Excel Data into MySQL in 5 Easy Steps](http://blog.tjitjing.com/index.php/2008/02/import-excel-data-into-mysql-in-5-easy.html)

Comment: Might be, in my case description column may contains any string value ( ' , ) . so csv not suit for that. thanks for your suggestion